# How do I get a TP Link WN725 Nano wireless adapter working?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm using ubuntu on my packard bell desktop pc. I've installed ubuntu and it works fine. but alas i cant get my wifi dongle to work in it.

The dongle is a tp link wn725n nano adapter.

The dongle still works fine when i switch to windows but not found in ubuntu. i've connected the computer directly with a ethernet cable and ubuntu goes online no problem. any hints or tips on how to locate and install the drivers into ubuntu would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the first step when you should preform is update your system. this may solve your problem already by itself.
open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

press enter and insert your password. your system should start updating

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

press enter and the system should start upgrading (may take a while)

after that reboot and check if your wireless network driver is working.
If not try the Ubuntu software centre, type in "tp link wn725n nano adaptor" or something alike. Many wireless drivers are available here.

Let us know how this turns out!

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. wont be able to test till tonight as i have to connect a 30ft ethernet cable to it to go online and with a 1 year old terrorist living with me its unfeasable to do during waking hours. thanks again. regards Mik.

Comment: Please see this post. I suggest, if at all possible, you use the native driver. http://askubuntu.com/questions/377470/tp-link-wn725n-unable-to-get-drivers-to-work-with-13-04-after-upgrade-worked-o/377482#377482