# TP-Link WN725N, unable to get drivers to work with 13.04 after upgrade (worked on 12.10 and prior)

Tags: 13.04, wireless, drivers, compatibility

I went back to my desktop after a bunch of months not using it, and I decided to upgrade Ubuntu to the newest version (I was still in 12.04). I had to download a driver for my TP-Link USB wireless device (TL-WN725N, chip RTL8188eu), which worked flawlessly in 12.04, then stopped working after the upgrade to 12.10. I recompiled the driver and it worked again (My router is pretty far from my room so I can't really use an ethernet cable without moving it).

Then problems started! After upgrading to 13.04, it gives me an error when I try to run it. I looked on google and found many solutions, but always with the RTL8188CUS chip, which isn't using the same driver as mine... So I'm kinda stuck! I could plug it to upgrade to 13.10, but I have no idea if my driver will work better on this version.

Any solution? I would paste the error, but I'm at work currently. I'll add it later when I'm home, if needed to fix the problem!

Thanks! I love Ubuntu, hope I'll find a way to make it compatible with my wireless! :)

Comment: Why did you NOT attempt to upgrade directly to **14.04 LTS**, from 12.04? You will have issues under 12.10, 13.04 or 13.10 that are not possible to address. ***All three are now end-of-life.*** I would personally recommend a new / clean install of **14.04.2 LTS**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are quite certain that it's an RTL8188eu chip, then I suggest this package: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/archive/master.zip Right-click the zip file and select 'Extract Here.' Then, in a terminal:

```
cd rtl8188eu-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

If you are unsure if it's an RTL8188eu chip, please post:

```
lsusb
```

The file I linked above 'makes' perfectly on my 13.10 system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. 

I am 99% confident it's the 8188eu chip, but I'll look and post the lsusb infos here as soon as I am home. I'll also try your solution later, the driver I downloaded wasn't the same.